# parsing JSON with missing fields

Tags: python, json

I have json array with very dynamic field and some of the array doesn't have all the fields.
Example :

```
[ 
{
      "Name": "AFG LIMITED",
        "Vendor ID": "008343",
        "EGID": "67888",
         "FID": "83748374"
     },
{
        "Name": "ABC LIMITED",
        "Vendor ID": "008333",
        "EGID": "67888",
        "AID": "0000292"
         "FID": "98979"
    },
    ]
```

I need to extract particular key with header & pipe delimiter like :Name|Vendor ID|EGID|AID(only present in second array).if any key is not present then it should have null value
I was try to parse this with below code but it's breaking in the second line itself as AID is missing.

```
import json

with open("sample.json", "r") as rf:
    decoded_data = json.load(rf)

# Check is the json object was loaded correctly
try:
    for i in decoded_data:
      print i["Name"],"|",i["Vendor ID"]"|",i["EGID"],"|",i["AId"]
       
except KeyError:
    print(null)
```

output from above code:
AFG LIMITED|008343|67888|null

Comment: `i.get(key, default_value)`

Comment: Thanks, but its printing the same code with below error:  print i.get(["Name"],""),"|",i.get(["Vendor ID"],""),"|",i.get(["EGID"],""),"|",i.get(["AId"],"")
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @RaviKumar The `key` parameter should just be a string, e.g. `"Name"` and not `["Name"]`. You don't need to add the square brackets since you're calling a method and not using the square bracket operator to do the lookup. The `TypeError` is a result of Python interpreting the square brackets as a list, and lists as keys are not allowed as lists cannot be hashed.

Comment: Thanks, i changed it to just string and worked but I am wondering how can i print the same header which i am using as print , please suggest.

Comment: @RaviKumar Simply set the default value to `"null"` instead of an empty string (e.g. `i.get("Name", "null")`) and the fields that don't exist would have a value of "null" in the output.

Comment: yes, Thanks but can you please help me to get the header also.